# How to correctly display data stored in an external model without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I am trying to display a User's name on top of a box where they enter their Employee # in a form, without having to refresh the page.

For example, they enter their # and then after they click/tab onto the next field, it renders their name on top, which comes from the database, so the user knows they've entered the correct info. This name is stored in a separate model, so I try to retrieve it using the "id/number".

I am not too familiar with AJAX but after reading a few similar questions it seems like an AJAX request would be the most appropriate way to achieve this. I tried to make a function **get_employee_name** that returns the name of the person based on the way I saw another ajax request worked, but I'm not sure how to implement this so it displays after the # is entered.

My page currently loads, but when I check the network using F12, there is never a call to the function/url that searches for the name to display it on the page. I'm not sure where I might be missing the part that connects these two areas of the code, but I have a feeling it has to do with the html tag where the call is supposed to happen, as I am not too familiar with html and Django.

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,  blank=True)
```

This is the model where the name is stored

**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='number', primary_key=True)
```

I was reading I can add to the "attrs" in the widget an 'onchange' part, but I am not too familiar with how to approach this and tying it to the ajax request from forms and not the html.

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')
```

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do submission stuff..


def get_employee_name(request):
    employee_number = request.GET.get('employee_number')

    try:
        employee = Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number)
    except Salesman.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Employee not found'}, status=404)

    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return JsonResponse({'employee_name': employee_name})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations, name='ajax_load_stations'),
    path('get-employee-name/', views.get_employee_name, name='ajax_get_employee_name'),
]
```

The ajax request I tried to create is at the end of this html. I modified a similar request I found, but it does not actually display anything on the screen, not sure if I'm missing an area where the request is actually never being called, as I am not too familiar with how these types of requests work.

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-stations-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_load_stations' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <h1 get-employee-name-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_get_employee_name' %}"></h1>
            <div>
                {{ form.employee_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<!-- This is the dependent dropdown script -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#id_work_area").change(function () {
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("data-stations-url");
            var workAreaId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'work_area': workAreaId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#my-hidden-div").show(); // show it
                    $("#id_station_number").html(data);
                    // Check the length of the options child elements of the select
                    if ($("#id_station_number option").length == 1) {
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().hide(); // Hide parent of the select node
                    } else {
                        // If any option, ensure the select is shown
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
     </script>

<!-- -->

    <script>
        $("#id_employee_number").change(function () {
            var employee_number = $(this).val();
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("get-employee-name-url");

            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:'GET',
            data: {
                'id': employee_number
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var employee_name = data['employee_name'];
                $('#employee_name')[0].innerHTML = employee_name;
            },
            error : function (data) {
                var error_message = data['error'];
                $('#employee_name')[0].innerHTML = error_message;
            }
            });
        });
    </script>

{% endblock main %}
```

What could be causing nothing to render on the page? Is there a call missing in the html portion?

I assume there needs to be a place where the onchange() goes, but I'm not sure where this would be in since the form fields are it's own thing, without tags.

Comment: Have you tried to add a debugger on your js in order to see whether all things are working properly?

Comment: Agreed with @almanegra, put your URL directly in your JS code as you are working with template, and since it's a static url, use `let` instead of `var`. You should be able to see all the requests made by your page in the terminal where you started the Django development server, post those requests so we know what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up a bit with my previous comment. Since you are using JS inside django templates (which I do not like much) the suggestion is using `let url = "{% url 'operations:ajax_get_employee_name' %}"` on your JS code (django templates will resolve this automatically)

Comment: @almanegra I tried making this change but still nothing gets called. I have never used JS/ajax requests, so I made this based off of another one that was already in the code that creates a dependent dropdown, so I'm not even sure if the ajax is even valid. I have added the other script to kinda give an idea of what I attempted to do to create this request.

Comment: Is this code hosted in a git repo so that we can try to reproduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to

```
var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("get-employee-name-url");
```

The id is referring to the form which does not have an attribute name "get-employee-name-url". Your url is actually in here

```
<h1 get-employee-name-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_get_employee_name' %}"></h1>
```

So maybe add an id to it like this

```
<h1 id="url" get-employee-name-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_get_employee_name' %}"></h1>
```

and then you can access it like you were

```
var url = $("#url").attr("get-employee-name-url");
```